# How to convert datetime to date in JPQL?

Tags: sql, spring, jpa

What's the problem with this code?

```
@Query(value = "Select " +
    "date(ivd.trnDatetime) as date, " +
    "ivd.binNo as bin, " +
    "ivd.snNo as sn, " +
    "count(ivd.invoiceNo) as totInvoice, " +
    "sum(ivd.totSaleAmt) as totSaleAmt " +
    "from InvoiceData ivd where ivd.status = 1 group by date(ivd.trnDatetime), ivd.binNo, ivd.snNo")
List<Object[]> getDailyTransactionReport();
```

It throws

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 +-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
 |  +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'date' {originalText=date}
 |  \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
 |     \-[DOT] DotNode: 'invoicedat0_.transaction_at' {propertyName=trnDatetime,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=trnDatetime,path=ivd.trnDatetime,tableAlias=invoicedat0_,className=com.efdms.transactionmonitoring.domain.InvoiceData,classAlias=ivd}
 |        +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'invoicedat0_.id' {alias=ivd, className=com.efdms.transactionmonitoring.domain.InvoiceData, tableAlias=invoicedat0_}
 |        \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'trnDatetime' {originalText=trnDatetime}
 [Select date(ivd.trnDatetime) as date, ivd.binNo as bin, ivd.snNo as sn, count(ivd.invoiceNo) as totInvoice, sum(ivd.totSaleAmt) as totSaleAmt from com.efdms.transactionmonitoring.domain.InvoiceData ivd where ivd.status = 1 group by date(ivd.trnDatetime), ivd.binNo, ivd.snNo]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:729)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:351)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy190.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87)
    ... 62 common frames omitted
```

The property for `trnDatetime` in entity

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "transaction_at", nullable = false)
private Instant trnDatetime;
```

and equivalent column in SqlServer is `datetime`

Answer (score 13):

JPQL does not support `date()` and so your query fails.You have the following options :

1. Change to use the native SQL by setting `nativeQuery=true` in `@Query`
2. If you are using Hibernate , use the HQL specific [`cast()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-functions) that cast `trnDatetime` to `LocalDate` :

```sql
select cast(ivd.trnDatetime as LocalDate) as date ,
       count(ivd.invoiceNo) as totInvoice 
       from InvoiceData ivd 
       where ivd.status = 1 
       group by cast(ivd.trnDatetime as LocalDate)"
```

*<sub>I ignore other columns for the sake of brevity</sub>*

Please note that the index 0 in each item of the result list is a `LocalDate`

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you that there is no value for `transaction_at`. This means that some records in your table have a `null` value for `transaction_at` or that it is not selected by the query for some reason. You will need to make sure that you `select` it and in case it is `null` you will either have a default value for it, or you filter out records which have `null` as a value for that particular field.

Also, if a value for `transaction_at` is not necessarily required, then you can remove `nullable = false` from the `@Column`.

EDIT

The solution, as pointed out in the comment section was `CAST(ivd.trnDatetime AS date)`

Comment: Thanks, but it is a not null-able field in DB also and there is no null value for this field in DB.

Comment: @shovon then you will need to make sure that you select it. The definition expects a field with that name and your select doesn't have one.

Comment: I think the problem is in conversion. If I use `CONVERT(date, ivd.transaction_at) as date` and set `nativeQuery = true` then it works fine. But it would make it Database specific.

Comment: @shovon you name it as date, so in your result set there will be no transaction_at. Try CONVERT(date, ivd.transaction_at) as transaction_at