# How to truncate Time from a Timestamp in H2 and Postgresql with the same command?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, h2

We are using hibernate through jpa in java.
Applications uses postgresql in prod and h2 in memory database for tests.

In some functionality we are basically using "select date(timestampfield) from sometable" to cut off the time part of the timestamp and only have the date.

The problem comes when this goes into testing, because h2 does not know "date" as a function. h2 does this with "trunc". Bust postgres does not know "trunc".

Even switching h2 to postgres compatibility mode does not help.

So currently we have to change the code, so it checks whether we are testing and use this to switch between using "date" and "trunc".

I am hoping for a smarter way that does not require code changes to get this to work.

(Can't move the cutting of the time from select into code, because the actual use of the function is in a where clause where the time has to be ignored in a comparison.)

Comment: retrieve the value as datetime and convert in Java?  Or create a common function in H2

Comment: I don't see a `date()` function in documentation of PostgreSQL, but it seems to work exactly like standard cast specification `CAST(timestampValue AS DATE)`, so it is reasonable to use the standard syntax instead of this vendor-specific function.

Comment: Can you use HQL as shown here? [How to convert datetime to date in JPQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59124239/how-to-convert-datetime-to-date-in-jpql)

Comment: H2 [date_trunc](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#date_trunc), Postgres [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H2 and Postgres share the `date_trunc` function.

Also per the H2 docs [Trunc](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#trunc):

> This function with datetime or string argument is deprecated, use DATE_TRUNC instead. When used with a timestamp, truncates the timestamp to a date (day) value and returns a timestamp with or without time zone depending on type of the argument. When used with a date, returns a timestamp at start of this date. When used with a timestamp as string, truncates the timestamp to a date (day) value and returns a timestamp without time zone.

Example usage.

H2

```
select DATE_TRUNC('DAY', TIMESTAMP '2023-04-20 09:04:00')
2023-04-20 00:00:00
```

Postgres

```
select DATE_TRUNC('DAY', TIMESTAMP '2023-04-20 09:04:00');
2023-04-20 00:00:00
```

Or if you really just want a date:

H2

```
SELECT CAST(TIMESTAMP '2023-04-20 09:04:00' AS DATE)
2023-04-20
```

Postgres

```
SELECT CAST(TIMESTAMP '2023-04-20 09:04:00' AS DATE);
2023-04-20
```